# using complex or real analysis solve $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{x^m}{\sin x}dx$

Tags: integration, contour-integration, closed-form

closed form for $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{x^m}{\sin x}\ dx$$

I slove it for some m but in general i failed.

I tried by part , by substitution,by using $\sin x =\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$ .

I guess that $\sin x =\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$ then using geometric series lead to the answer,I used it and got something it seems related to Zeta function.

---

can any one solve it using residue theorem or using real analysis ?

Answer (score 0):

Well that's just a start, but I don't like this sin, so I tried this: I looked for a primitive of $\frac{1}{\sin(x)}$, which is $\ln(\tan(\frac{x}{2}))$ if  $0 < x < \frac{\pi}{2}$, and I used the change of variable :

$$ u = \ln\left(\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)\rightarrow du = \frac{dx}{\sin(x)}$$

$$x = 0 \rightarrow u = -\infty ;\quad  x=\frac{\pi}{2} \rightarrow u=0 $$

So, if I denote $I_m$ your integral, one gets:

$$ I_m = \int_{-\infty}^0 \left({2\arctan(e^u)}\right)^m du = 2^m \int_{-\infty}^0 \left({\arctan(e^u)}\right)^m du $$

If you let : $t= e^u \rightarrow dt = e^u du,\ u = -\infty \rightarrow t = 0 ; $ $ u=0 \rightarrow t=1 $ , you get:

$$I_m = 2^m\int_{0}^1 \frac{{\arctan^m(t)}}{t} dt  $$

This one is easier to treat I think, maybe the last change of variable was not the best. I'll edit if I can finish this

Comment: please use latex - slashes before trig functions, and double dollar signs.

Comment: Ok, but I'm not very used to it, I'll see if I can improve the post

Comment: Ok I got it, thanks nbubis